# Automating the process of identifying subgroups of a pandas dataframe that do not significantly differ on a value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have the following dataframe, which, for the sake of this example, is full of random numbers:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['Category'] = np.random.randint(1, 3, df.shape[0])
df.head()

     A    B    C    D  Category
0  417   88  924  844         2
1  647  136   57  680         2
2  223  883  837   56         2
3  346   94   19   80         1
4  635  863  405   29         1
```

I need to find a subset of n rows (say, 80 rows), which do not significantly differ (p> .05) on the value "C" between two category groups (thus, between categories 1 and 2).

I perform the following t-test to test if the difference is significant:

```
# t-test
cat1 = df[df['Category']==1]
cat2 = df[df['Category']==2]

ttest_ind(cat1['C'], cat2['D'])
```

Output:

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=-2.004339328381308, pvalue=0.047793084338372295)
```

Currently, I am doing this manually, using trial and error. I do this by manually picking the subsets, testing them, and then retesting until I find the desired result. I am curious to hear if there is a way to automate this process.

Comment: Are you looking for the first subset where this happens?

Comment: @rpanai for these purposes it doesn't matter. The first one will be great, but it also doesn't matter if it is not the first subset instance.

Comment: You could use itertools.combinations for df.index on a loop till you don't find a list of index that satisfies you condition. It looks to me slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, by using `combinations` from `itertools` as rightfully suggested by @rpanai with `groupby` and `pipe`that enables you to get different groups within the same operation. You return a Boolean for the pvalue being above or below threshold 0.05 and you break the loop when Boolean is True:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['Category'] = np.random.randint(1, 3, df.shape[0])
df.head()

list_iter = [idx for idx in combinations(df.Category.unique(), 2)]
test = dict()

for i, j in list_iter:
    test[(i, j)] = df.groupby("Category").pipe(lambda g: ttest_ind(g["C"].get_group(i), 
                                               g["C"].get_group(j))[1] > 0.05)
    if test[(i, j)]:
        break
```

Here, in this example, the dictionary `test` is:

```
{(2, 1): True}
```

It works with any numbers of groups, for instance if Category has three groups,  with `df['Category'] = np.random.randint(1, 4, df.shape[0])`, the output for `test` would look like:

```
{(2, 3): True}
```

**EDIT** : If you want the values of A for a successful test, you can do the following:

```
list_iter = [idx for idx in combinations(df.Category.unique(), 2)]
test = dict()
for i, j in list_iter:
    test[(i, j)] = df.groupby("Category").pipe(lambda g: ttest_ind(g["C"].get_group(i),
                                                        g["C"].get_group(j))[1] > 0.05)
    if test[(i, j)]:
        output = df.loc[df["Category"].isin([i,j]), ["Category", "A"]]
        break
```

I replaced `D` with `C` because re-reading your question you say you want to compare `C` across different values of `Category`. If it is not `C` but `C` and `D`, `combinations` won't iter across all the groups you want.
I also changed the Boolean to being above 0.05, since you want the groups that are not significantly different.

Here I have the following result for `test`:

```
{(2, 3): True}
```

and for `output`:

```
   Category    A
0          2  510
1          3  988
2          2  595
```

You get the values of `A` for the two categories `2` and `3` where values of `C` were **not significantly** different.

Comment: thank you for the thorough response. One question I have is, what does "[1]" indicate in the code you provided (get_group(j))[1] < 0.05)?

Comment: No problem :) It means I only take the pvalue as the `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` returns both the statistic and the pvalue, but you only want to pvalue to compare with threshold.

Comment: Thank you for all that helpful information!
I am still struggling to figure out how to retrieve the original values that are associated with the results.
So, for instance, at the end of this, what is the best way to retrieve all "A" values that are associated with the final combinations? This seems tricky because a groupby was employed to categories.

Comment: @arkadiy I corrected the above to answer your question and match your desired output

Comment: thank you!!!! It works like Swiss clockwork. I really appreciate your help with this!